# How do I pass get request parameters to my Velocity Template to send mails

Tags: jsp, servlets, velocity

I have a JSP and in that JSP I have a link which looks something like

http://mydomain.com/verify.do?email=emailid&id=123

Now when users clicks that link, it goes to my velocityview servlet, now my question is how do I pull out those parameters in velocity servlet and put it into the context so that I can send it to my template.

I tried getparameter,#set(#request.getAttribute(email) etc.But for some reason I dont see the value getting into the context or template.

I know there is velocity parameter tool out there,but I am not able to find as how to install and use it.So appreciate if someone can point me to right direction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is the [Velocity context](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/developer-guide.html#The_Context).  In your backing Java class or Velocity servlet, read in the parameters and put them in the context:

```
context.put("email", request.getParameter("email"));
context.put("id", request.getParameter("id"));
```

Then in your Velocity template you can reference them as `$email` and `$id`.

Answer (score 1):

In the accepted answer you have to explicitly unwind all the arguments in your controller.  So if you have 5 fields, you have 5 of the above statements.

I would suggest:

```
context.put("request", request);
```

Then in your template something like this:

```
<p>Is the Jump Run Heading Good? <b>$request.getParameter("heading")</b></p>
```

Maybe you could write a little macro to avoid that last little bit of ugliness. You write a little helper function to loop through the request parameters names with getParameterNames() and call getParameter() on each.

Comment: This is definitely more concise, but it also tightly couples the Velocity template to the Request object.  It's a trade-off, to be sure...

Comment: Agreed. That's why I mentioned you could write a little helper function to take all the parameters and put them on a map.

But so much work to get so little bang! I've been moving most of my green field web apps to python where a dictionary is a dictionary is a dictionary.

Comment: Though the suggestion is great,I dont have more work to do here,Just send the verification mail with email/UUID appended to url.Email template is velocity template.Maybe later as my site and requirements grow, I might have to go via this root.Thanks Robert and Evan.